# Nodejs page not loading when rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am using Nodejs and Mongoose. When I render the page nothing happens, the page just attempts to load. When I write to the console i can view all the entries in the collection (Kp). Please assist, as to what is wrong in my code.

```
router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    const arrayT = [];
    Kp.find({})
        .then(element => {
            arrayT.forEach(function (element) {
                arrayT.push({
                    summary: element.summary,
                    detailDesc: element.detailDesc
                });
                res.render('list', { arrayT });
            })

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: You're rendering inside the `arrayT.forEach` callback, but arrayT is empty to start, so that will never run.

Comment: Thanks @IceMetalPunk just to confirm, the problem is where i am render `/list` ?

Comment: Yes. Also, you're pushing to arrayT inside a forEach of arrayT, which makes no sense. Really, you shouldn't be using `arrayT.forEach` if you're explicitly making arrayT empty, as that will not do anything and the callback will never run.

Comment: TL;DR: You probably meant to do `element.forEach` instead (assuming element comes back with an array of values from the database), and then to render the list view outside the forEach.

Comment: When I run run the code like this it works `Kp.find({}, function(err, docs){
    const arrayT = [];
    docs.forEach(function(element){
        console.log(arrayT);
        arrayT.push({
            summary: element.summary,
            detailDesc: element.detailDesc
        });
    });
});`

Comment: Notice that you're using `docs.forEach` in that new code, not `arrayT.forEach`. You're iterating over the returned documents, not the arrayT array. That's the main difference. You can certainly use the Promise syntax you originally tried, but you need to iterate over the right array :D (And only render after the loop is done, of course.)

Comment: Technically, you could simplify your code to remove the forEach and replace it witrh a map: `.then(docs => res.render('list', docs.map(({summary, detailDesc}) => {summary, detailDesc})))` If you don't need the arrayT later, that is.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Im getting 1 record back :D at least. I know you said I must render when the loop is done. This is the code, should I pass it to an array inside the loop and render outside. Take a look at the code, `router.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    Kp.find({}, function(err, docs){
        docs.forEach(function(element){
            res.render('list', {
                summary: element.summary,
                detailDesc: element.detailDesc
            });          
        });
    });
});`

Comment: Again: do not render inside a loop. That's almost never a good idea (in fact, I can't think of any situation where rendering more than once per request is a good idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem

```
router.get('/list', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const list = await Kp.find({}).select('summary detailDesc -_id');
        list.forEach(function(element){});
        res.render('list', {list});
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: 'Test is not working ' + err });
        console.log(err);
    }

});
```

Thank you all for assisting with comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrayT.forEach isn't iterating over anything since arrayT is empty and because it doesn't iterate over anything the res.render() line of code isn't ever hit.  You could prove this with console.log();

My advice to you is to utilize async await and avoid promises as they can potentially lead to nested code like callbacks.

Preferred code:

```
router.get('/list', async (req, res) => {
 try {
const arrayT = [];
const listOfKPs = await Kp.find({})
listOfKPs.forEach( ele => {
 arrayT.push({
    summary: element.summary,
    detailDesc: element.detailDesc
   });
  });
  return res.render('list', { arrayT });
 }
 catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
   return res.render('list', { [] }); // render empty list
 }
});
```

Comment: I ran the code and 'summary' is undefined in the browser. `9|     <tr class="col-lg-auto">

    10|         

 >> 11|           <td><%= summary %> </td>

    12|           <td> <%= detailDesc %> </td>    

    13|       

    14|       


summary is not defined`

Comment: Try doing console.log(arrayT) to see whether there are values there or not.  Other than that I can't assist you with the other code since it isn't in this post.

Comment: Also if this solves your problem can you please mark it as the correct answer with the checkbox below the arrows.

Comment: I will definitely mark it, when I console.log(arrayT) I can see all the entries in the collection.

Comment: Just a question, could the problem be at how I build my model? Reason being, I can retrieve a record but its always the last record. this is how the code looks like `const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    summary:{
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   detailDesc:{
    type: String,
    required: false
    },
   date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    } 
});

const Kp = mongoose.model('Kp', UserSchema);
module.exports = Kp;`

Comment: I believe your query is a select all within the Mongo world.  Not sure why you're only receiving one instead of an array of the entire collection.  Either way try **console.log(listOfKPs) and **console.log(arrayT)** in order to see whats going on.  Also run your mongo cli and see if you have any data there to compare.

Comment: Can you check the answer since it answered your original question.

Comment: I've just ran the cli and performed the find() in mongo and I can view all the entries when i add a new entry it retrieves the last 1 i've entered

Comment: Thee data was retrieved before the answer, in the with the follow code that i've ran. `Kp.find({}, function(err, docs){
    const arrayT = [];
    docs.forEach(function(element){
        console.log(arrayT);
        arrayT.push({
            summary: element.summary,
            detailDesc: element.detailDesc
        });
    });
});` but the code received from the answer did not retrieve any data. It attempts to load the page but nothing occurred.